# How can I hide query string parameters using the Post, Redirect, Get pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, wizard

I have a multi-step data entry form in my ASP.NET MVC application.

When the information is posted, the input values are checked and if I determine that some related data is required (e.g. a purchase order references a supplier that does not exist) I redirect to another action so that the user can enter the extra data.

I do not want the values that have already been entered by the user to be lost between pages so I am passing these to the second action method using a viewModel. The data is contained in hidden inputs on the second page so that the user can not see them.

This works fine except I end up with a URL that looks something like this:

> myDomain/RFQ/CreatePart?PartNumber=Skateboard&Supplier=Bobs%20skateboards&DateCreated=08%2F28%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00&DateRequired=08%2F28%2F2012%2000%3A00%3A00&Quantities=1%2C%203%20%26%205%20off

I have tried simply returning a view instead of redirecting which gives me the URL Like this:

> myDomain/RFQ/CreatePart

However, this gives me the problem of the user being able to repost the values by refreshing the browser as I am now no longer following the post, redirect, Get pattern.

Is there a way of properly using the *Post-Redirect-Get* pattern whilst maintaining the cleaner URL?

---

**Update 29th September 2012**

I investigated the options listed below and have decided on using `SessionState` for the time being as this allows me to store intermediate data until the user has finished their transaction whilst allowing me to use the *post-redirect-get* pattern with a clean URL.

I was actually aware of `SessionState` prior to asking this question but unfortunately some of the information I had read about it had led me to believe this was not the best solution (most articles cite poor performance but rarely provide any evidence of this or explain why).

Having read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net) article I now understand `SessionState` a lot better.

Comment: You may put intermediate steps data into session? In this case you will be able to use PRG and user won't be able to rewrite data.

Comment: you can also try a cookie or session etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Options are as follows (order does not imply better or worse)

1. Add the values to `TempData` and they will be available until they are read on the next request by that user and then automatically cleared.
2. Save the intermediate steps to the database.
3. Save the intermediate steps In the `Cache` (if the data is **shared** amongst users).
4. Save the intermediate steps to the `SessionState` (if the data is **per**-user).
5. who cares in this case if it's an ugly intermediate URL?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the TempData method is appropriate in this situation. When I redirect, I pass the TempData to my view. If the user refreshes, the TempData has bean cleared leaving the user with a blank form (I use DisplayFor to display some of the data entered on the previous step).

Comment: If you potentially need it on multiple occasions, you'l need to try setting it after reading it so its available again for the next request. Personally, I'd cache each step, thats just me but you can test/mock a cached dependency using some ICache interface you inject into your controllers. TempData on the otherhand has fairly non-testable behavior. A cache entry you know should exist until you specifically clear it (at the start or end of a wizard or once the user resaves that step)

Comment: when you talk about using the cache is that the same as using session or something else altogether?

Comment: nope, something different - see: http://blog.overridethis.com/blog/post/2009/03/11/CachingAbstractionSolution-NET3-5.aspx